# How to define a symbol that can be used in both a glossary and an equation?

Tags: math-mode, glossaries, nomenclature

I created a list of symbols table as you can see :

```
\newglossaryentry{slambda}{
name=$\lambda$,
description={wavelength}
}
```

When I tried to put this symbol in the equation :

```
\begin{equation} 
\gls{slambda} = \frac{c}{f} 
\end{equation}
```

I got an error. I want to do that to show the symbol Lambda in my symbol list, generated as below :

```
\printglossary
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit (e.g., tell us what you did to create the list of symbols table, what did you try without success)?

Comment: I'm trying to add symbol in the tag 'equation' to see them in the symbol table, because if I don't add them, I can't see them (I don't know if I'm pretty clear or not, english not my native language ...)

Comment: @Zaertiu: If you show us the code how you generated the list of symbols table, it's possible to help you, as of now -- we can only guess

Comment: post edited, I shall be clearer now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some will frown on this, but the error is `$\lambda$` being used in `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` when `\gls{slambda}` is replaced with `$\lambda$` then.

It's not possible to use `$...$` inside `equation`-like environments.

Omitting works for the environment, but then `\printglossaries` complains about missing math mode.

One possible solution is to apply `\ensuremath` around `\lambda`. It will use math mode if it's not already in math mode then -- so it is safe to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{slambda}{%
name=\ensuremath{\lambda},
description={wavelength}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation} 
\gls{slambda} = \frac{c}{f} 
\end{equation}

\printglossary  % for usage with makeglossaries program


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zaertiu: Alright: Happy TeXing then ;-)

Comment: This is a place where `\ensuremath` *is* good. `;-)`

Comment: +1 but minor nit-pick `;-)` Both `\printglossary` and `\printglossaries` will have the same effect here as there's only one glossary. They're not dependent on the document build. (`\printglossaries` just iterates over all defined glossaries and applies `\printglossary[type={...}]` to each one.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Thanks, this is one of my older answers related to `glossaries`. I changed to `\printglossary` here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oops, sorry I didn't notice the date!

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: No worries. In fact, I am using more than one glossary in my 'coding system' for teaching that I always use `\printglossaries`, I think this dates back to the time of answering this question as well.