# \newcommand, \begin{math} and \newglossaryentry

Tags: math-mode, macros, glossaries

I have the following code snippet:

```
\newcommand{\jbv}[0]{j_{bv}}
\newcommand{\txtjbv}[0]{\begin{math}\jbv\end{math}}
\newglossaryentry{jbv}{name={\txtjbv}, sort={a03}, description={Bla}}
```

I get the following error:

```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@ 
                                  ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
l.27 ...3}, description={Bla}}
```

It seems that this is caused by `name={\txtjbv}` on the third line of the snippet, because it works when I just use `name={jbv}`.

**How can I get those newcommands properly in order to use them inside my text, in equations and as the glossary name?**

Comment: Is this nesting really needed? Either use `\ensuremath{\jbv}}` or `\glssetnoexpandfield{name}` but I don't recommend this

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259197/31729

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The `name` field defaults to no expansion. It's the `text` field that's expanding and causing the problem, but I agree it's much simpler just to use `name={\ensuremath{\jbv}}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you want to answer?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: No, you know your package much (much,much) better of course -- I think, you 'should' answer ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Okay, done :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `math` environment, identified with `\begin{math}...\end{math}`, is fragile (but `$...$` isn't) and so can break in an expandable context. By default, [expansion](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:expansion) is on for all fields except `name`, `description`, `descriptionplural`, `symbol` and `symbolplural`. (The exceptions are for backward-compatibility because early versions of the `glossaries` package had to write the name, description and symbol to the external glossary file, so those fields were sanitized instead of being expanded on definition.)

So in this case, `\begin{math}...\end{math}` doesn't get expanded when the `name` field is assigned, but it does get expanded when the other implicit fields (such as `text`) that take their default values from the `name` key are assigned.

As mentioned by Christian in the comments, it's much better to use `\ensuremath` in this situation. Although `\ensuremath` can cause problems in other contexts, it's the most convenient way of ensuring maths mode within glossary fields so that `\gls` can be used in either maths or text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\jbv}[0]{j_{bv}}
\newcommand{\txtjbv}[0]{\begin{math}\jbv\end{math}}
\newglossaryentry{jbv}{name={\ensuremath{\jbv}},sort={a03},description={Bla}}

\begin{document}
In text: \gls{jbv}. In an equation:
\begin{equation}\gls{jbv}\end{equation}

In the glossary:
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```